# Android layout 2x3 static evenly sized grid of images

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a grid of 6 (2 columns x 3 rows) images which do not change in size depending on the ImageView contained in the grid and the sizes should be the same for all elements of the grid, exactly the same height and width, and the images in the grid should scale to fit inside these boxes.  They will initially contain a sort of boiler plate image which will be replaced with a photo.  The code I have currently produces some unexpected and non-intuitive results.  When I add photos to the grid to replace the original image, the sizes do not remain static, and I cannot make sense of how Android decides to layout these sizes.  I have shown some different background colors in some screenshots to maybe make it a bit more evident which part of the screen belongs to which View or element in the Android layout, but the behavior really makes no sense to me.  It seems a ridiculously difficult task to tell create a grid with a static, even size, regardless of what it contains.  I am using a `TableLayout` for the grid.  It seemed like the right choice for such a task.  Here is the XML layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/root_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/ship_header_padding">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="VIN: "
                    android:id="@+id/vin_txt"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/ship_header_txt_sz"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:id="@+id/vin"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/ship_header_txt_sz"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="Model: "
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:id="@+id/ymm_txt"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/ship_header_txt_sz"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:id="@+id/ymm"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/ship_header_txt_sz"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp">
        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="0dp">
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:rotation="90"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:rotation="90"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="0dp">
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                    android:rotation="90"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:rotation="90"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="0dp">
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:rotation="90"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:rotation="90"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here are some screen shots of the results depending on how many images are on the screen.

[image: No Image][image: Single Image] [image: Double Image] [image: Triple Image]

Can anyone tell me the magic combination of attributes which creates a layout which scales the images within it and does not change in size?  These Android layouts are incredibly confusing and frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by changing the `TableLayout` to a set of nested `LinearLayout`.  It seems that it's not possible to achieve the desired result with a `TableLayout`, but it might be that I just don't know how to do it.  In any case, here is the resulting code which produced a 2x3 grid whose element size does not change, regardless of what the size of the contained images are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/root_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/ship_header_padding">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="VIN: "
                    android:id="@+id/vin_txt"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/ship_header_txt_sz"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:id="@+id/vin"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/ship_header_txt_sz"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="Model: "
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:id="@+id/ymm_txt"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/ship_header_txt_sz"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:id="@+id/ymm"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/ship_header_txt_sz"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:rotation="90"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:rotation="90"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:rotation="90"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:rotation="90"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:rotation="90"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:rotation="90"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```